# link mercurial repo to web server

Tags: nginx, web-server, repository, mercurial

I have the following situation:

In the same machine I have a mercurial server and a web server. The project repository is located at /var/hg/repos/myproyect and the public files for web server are in /usr/share/nginx/www

Is any way to link (ln) the repo directory to public path server? when I do

```
ln /var/hg/repos/myproject/.hg/store/data/ /ush/share/nginx/www/myproject
```

and I put in the browser http://iptoserver.com/myproject is shown nothing

I noted that store data in .hg ending in .i extension

Answer (score 2):

You should almost certainly setup hgweb to serve the repository rather than dumping the raw files.

The [Publishing Repositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories) and [HGWeb Step-by-Step](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep) wiki articles covers this in depth, but here are the highlights:

1. Create a hgweb.conf file (usually in `/usr/local/etc/` or something virtual host dependent in multitenant environments).

   ```
   [paths]
   myproject = /var/hg/repos/myproject

   [web]
   allow_archive = gz
   contact = Some Name <EMail@Example.com>
   ```
2. Copy the hgweb.cgi file from the installation directory to your cgi-bin directory. More likely than not: `cp /usr/share/mercurial/www/hgweb.cgi /var/www/cgi-bin/` (You get the idea anyway).
3. Edit the hgweb.cgi file, set the config file location from #1.
4. Configure nginx for fcgi:

   ```
   location /hg/ {
       fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
       include         fastcgi_hg;
       fastcgi_intercept_errors    off;

       limit_except GET HEAD {
           auth_basic  'Example';
           auth_basic_user_file /srv/hg.htpasswd;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Configure the fcgi include (`fastcgi_hg`) for hg:

   ```
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/hg)(.*)$;
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_path_info;
   fastcgi_param  AUTH_USER          $remote_user;
   fastcgi_param  REMOTE_USER        $remote_user;
   ```
6. Restart nginx and Bob's your uncle!

Comment: thanks! maybe I didn't explain well. for example, if I push a info.php file containing phpinfo(), I would like to see what phpinfo() returns not raw info.php file